# Python: Bytes not being converted properly?

Tags: python, encoding, byte, decoding

I'm VERY new to binary stuff, and I'm struggling a little bit.
I'm trying to convert a binary file to text. So far, this is my code:

```
 with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
  data = f.read()
  temp_data = str(data)

  if temp_data[-1] == '\\':
    temp_data = temp_data[:-1]

  temp_data = bytes(temp_data, 'utf-8')
  text = temp_data.decode('utf-8')
```

It seems to be working... partially. I see some things in the long byte string that I want to see, like a file name and timestamp. However, I'm still 
seeing a lot of byte values. The value of the text variable is:

```
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00T\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004\x01\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x01\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00TCODEF1001.DAR_MeasLog.2019-03-05+01:10:45.2019-03-05+01:11:21.1.100.0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x95\xcc}\\\xba\xcc}\\LOG\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00OKL\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00VKL\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00YKL\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00h\xcc}\\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xa4\xcc}\\\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00M\x00\x00\x00\x95\xcc}\\\xb9\xcc}\\'
```

I have no idea how to fix this, or what any of this means.

Note: I needed to parse the string for the last character '\' because the decoding was giving me an error " could not decode because last character is '\'", or something along those lines.

Thank you!

EDIT: I changed the code so now it looks like this:

```
 with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
  data = f.read()

  readable_str = data.decode('utf-16')
  bytes_again = readable_str.encode('utf-16')
```

When I print readable_str, I'm getting non-ASCII values which should not happen at all. I get text like this:

```
TĴŘŸ䍔䑏䙅〱㄰䐮剁䵟慥䱳杯㈮㄰ⴹ㌰〭⬵㄰ㄺ㨰㔴㈮㄰ⴹ㌰〭⬵㄰ㄺ㨱ㄲㄮㄮ〰〮첕屽첺屽佌G䭏L䭖L䭙L챨屽첤屽M첕屽첹屽
```

The decoding does not work with 'utf-8' or 'utf-32'. Is there a way to tell what decoding to use based of this? Are there other encodings out there that I have not tried? Thanks!

Comment: `temp_data = str(data)` almost certainly not what you want to do....

Comment: To convert the `bytes` to text, i.e. to a `str`, use `text = f.read().decode()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I do text = f.read().decode(), I'm getting this error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 0: invalid start byte. I had this error before and was able to work my way around it by using the above code. Is there a better way to fix this problem?

Comment: Yeah, your file isn't encoded using utf-8, so find the correct encoding

Comment: it's ascii encondig just install the unidecode library

Comment: Your sample looks like a binary data structure, where only a portion is what looks like plain ASCII text.  You need to know the format of the binary data to extract just the encoded text portion and decode it.

Answer (score 0):

The approach in Python3 for reading and writing data is much more explicit than what it used to be. *Almost* always assume bytes, decode before working with the data in the script and then encode back to bytes before writing out.
I highly recommend you watch nedbat's [talk](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) about Python's unicode and how to correctly work with bytes input/output.

Regardless, what you want to do is

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as fo:
    data = fo.read()  # This is in bytes

# We "decipher" the bytes  into something we can work with
readable_str = data.decode('utf-8')  

bytes_again = readable_str.encode('utf-8')
with open('other_file.txt', 'wb') as fw:
    fw.write(bytes_again)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Similar to the comment from @juanpa.arrivillaga, when I try to run your code it gives me the this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 0: invalid start byte
I was able to get around that error before with the above code. Is there a better way to fix this issue?

Comment: @helloworld95 One of the requirements for opening a file is also knowing its encoding. There is no way to accurately guess it like, say, a file's magic number can help guess a file's type. If you have some hints about the encoding (according to source?), that'll help you. Otherwise, you can bruteforce it until you see something that makes sense to you. If you started off with your own simple file and it gives you this error, start over with a fresh file and be sure to watch that talk - It's great!

Comment: I watched the video and it was very informative! It gave me a better understanding of Unicode and byte translation, however I'm not sure if it helped me figure out my problem (or maybe it did and it went over my head). I updated the question and now it's dealing with the decoding problem. Thanks!

Comment: Now, you need to make sure your output destination (terminal?) supports all characters you expect to see. The best test would be to try and read both files with the same program.